# Adjective for "occuring in two different planes or levels"

Tags: word-request

I'm trying to shorten

> He grew up in Ethiopia and moved to Canada at the age of 25. Those two worlds (occuring in two different levels), made him see how far man has reached.

into

> ...Those two (adjective here) worlds.

I'm looking for an adjective with the meaning described in addition to a figurative meaning of "one higher/better than the other. Off the top of my head, *unleveled*, *unparalleled*. I'm not sure those are correct. Feel free to suggest different constructions.

Answer (score 2):

I think the adjective you have is fine: different.

I also adjusted the sentence a little.

"He grew up in Ethiopia and moved to Canada at the age of 25. These two different worlds made him see how far man has come."

You could also express this as:

"He grew up in Ethiopia and moved to Canada at the age of 25. The vast differences between these two worlds made him see how far man has come."

Good synonyms you could use would be: distinct, divergent

Comment: Thank you. If you have time, I'd love to know the difference between _those_ and _these_.

Comment: Those refers to something farther away from the speaker. These refers to something nearer the speaker. These is ore appropriate for nouns mentioned in the previous sentence.

http://www.wikihow.com/Use-These-and-Those

Comment: So, I should have also said "not sure these are correct", right?

Comment: In that case, "they" would have been best.